# use generics to replace specific class type

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion

Currently, I have three classes, `Apple`, `Grape`, `Banana`, and I created a converter class (can convert a string to list) for each of them. Then I realized all those converter classes are basically the same except they take different class types. 
The example of `AppleConverter.java`

```
  public class AppleConverter extends StrutsTypeConverter {

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {

    final List<Apple> appleList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      for (String appleString : values) {
          Apple apple = Apple.valueOf(appleString);
          appleList.add(apple);
      }
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      throw new TypeConversionException(e);
    }
    return appleList;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (o instanceof List<?>) {
      List<Apple> list = (List<Apple>) o;
      String appleString = list
        .stream()
        .map(e -> String.valueOf(e))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
      return appleString;
    }
    throw new TypeConversionException("wrong");
  }
```

Basically, `GrapdeConverter.java` and `BananaConverter.java` are the same as `AppleConverter.java` except they take different class types. 
So I tried to create a generic class then those converter classes can inherit it.
My generic class code:

```
    public class FruitConverter<T> extends StrutsTypeConverter {


  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public Object convertFromString(Map context, String[] values, Class toClass) {
    if (ArrayUtils.isEmpty(values)) {
      return null;
    }
    final List<T> objs = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
      for (String objStr : values) {

           Object obj = toClass.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, objStr);

          objs.add(obj);
        }
      }
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      throw new TypeConversionException(e);
    }
    return objs;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
  @Override
  public String convertToString(Map context, Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return null;
    }
    if (o instanceof List<?>) {
      List<?> list = (List<?>) o;
      String fruitString = list
        .stream()
        .map(e -> String.valueOf(e))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
      return fruitString;
    }
    throw new TypeConversionException("object is not a list of objs");
  }
}
```

When I called `T obj = T.valueOf(objStr);`, it throws an error `can not resolve method valueOf`.
May anyone tell me how to apply generics correctly in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation error occurs because Java's generics are implemented with [type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339699/java-generics-type-erasure-when-and-what-happens). In this case, `T.valueOf` is treated as the same as if you had tried to do `Object.valueOf`, i.e. it doesn't know which classes to search in for the `valueOf` method except for `Object`.

You can pass the method in as a function using a method reference, as in the following example:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class FruitConverter<T> {
    private final Function<String, T> valueOf;

    FruitConverter(Function<String, T> valueOf) {
        this.valueOf = valueOf;
    }

    // ...
}

class AppleConverter extends FruitConverter<Apple> {
    AppleConverter() {
        super(Apple::valueOf);
    }
}
```

Then you can use `this.valueOf.apply(...)` when you want to call the method.

Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `T` in such expressions, I doubt that you even need generics for this task.

Quick and dirty way to generalize is to use reflection, instead of `T obj = T.valueOf(objStr);` use this:

```
Object obj = toClass.getDeclaredMethod("valueOf", String.class).invoke(null, objStr);
```

then you will be able to use same function for all objects like this.

Another approach is to use fabrics, but it will require much more code.

Comment: It seems I can not add obj to list<T>. I modified my answer and may you take a look at it?

Comment: @user3369592 you can cast it like `(T)obj`